# Firebase hosting shows blank screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I published a project on Firebase Hosting. It shows me blank screen. I check my code in my localhosting and It works smoothly. Also, I check the all question about this topic. Some of them suggest me try to flutter build web" on your terminal. But This time, gives me different error message. I tried changed href="/" tags to suggestions but it does not work. How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->


  <!--<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">-->
<!--  <base href="/">-->
  <!--<base href="/demostrationblogapp/">-->
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="unnamed_ik">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>medium-blog-feed-flutter</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
<!--<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=2330050811');
      });
    }
  </script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Web browser's log message:

[image]

Also, I tried to change firebase.json folder like this:

{
"hosting": {
"public": "build/web",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
]
}
}

When I tried to change build/web to web is still working. Also, I realized when I changed the 404 not found file. It works perfectly. So, I just need to publish my index.html page. How can I do that?

Lastly:
My app name is: medium-blog-feed-flutter
My firebase project's name is : demostrationblogapp

Last of Lastly: Here is the message when I used to "flutter build web" in my terminal again

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: ../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:432:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:440:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:451:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:463:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:475:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:487:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:499:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:510:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:521:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:532:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:544:15:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:96:17:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
        channel.setMockMessageHandler(null);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:98:17:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
        channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:111:17:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
        channel.setMockMessageHandler(null);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:113:17:
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
 ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
        channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:52:59:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
../../Documents/flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17:
Info: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                ^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.


Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                              8,8s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```